# How to share a fan robot with LEGO?

Tags: ideas

I've made a really awesome robot with LEGO Mindstorms EV3 (and I'd like not to say what it is here). I've seen fan robots on the LEGO site, and I wonder whether they could add mine on the site. I've seen a site for uploading ideas for LEGO ***kits***, but I can't find anywhere to upload robots. Can anyone please help?

Comment: Hmmm... so we can't send it directly to LEGO?

Comment: Not really. Imagine the amount of MOCs posted worldwide would also be sent to TLG. LEGO Ideas is the place you can submit your idea. And if you get enough likes from community it might be considered by TLG for production. However it is dedicated for something entirely new - old ideas, alternate models or something with licenses that TLG has agreement with most likely will be denied.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you don't quite understand how those robots became supported by Lego.

You see, EV3 was released in 2013, and they've supported only 12 fan robots. That's not a lot, and if they were still accepting fan robots for years they definitely would've had more robots on their site. I have an unofficial book by Laurens Valk about EV3 programming, in this book he has instructions for about 3 more of his robots. Yet none of them are on the site.

Why am I even mentioning a Lego fan and his book? Because [this page](https://www.lego.com/en-gb/themes/mindstorms/buildarobot) says that the race truck was designed by him. That's the only model he made that's on their site, but there are some people who have had multiple models of theirs accepted by Lego. They are Martyn Boogaarts and Kenneth Madsen. And I could've sworn that I saw a video(s) somewhere where they were interviewing the designers of these robots.

Looks like they were only accepting fan robots from **skilled** EV3 users.

Comment: Great answer! Wasn't aware of the actual "Fan robots" stuff. Do you happen to know the URL for these "Fan models"?

Comment: @Alex I'm sorry, I dont remember the link for the videos. Once again, I couldve sworn i saw them but I dont have time to look. If you want the general page about them, it's the hyperlink in my answer.

Comment: Is [this](https://www.lego.com/en-gb/themes/mindstorms/buildarobot) the page? I can count 12 models you've mentioned here.

Comment: @Alex yes, thats the one.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info, @mindstormsboi, and thanks particularly for the **skilled** comment.